# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') in MUI DataGridPro

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, frontend

I am trying to integrate a functionality of filtering instead of headerName using `renderHeader.
[MUI documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/header-filters/#simple-header-filters)
Its working fine Im applying filters on Name and Designation column but the problem is its not persisting its state for filters. If I apply filter on Name column and then apply filter to Designation the Name filter clears and designation filter applies. Here's the whole code snippet:

[Click Here to open sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/naughty-elion-vcw34l?file=%2Fdemo.js%3A208%2C54)

I have taken helped from ChatGPT aswell and its giving me error on the prop passed to dataGridPro component in filterModel. It expects an array maybe but when I pass in error then it gives error. Is their any fix for it?